# GoLang SPA returning 500 Internal Server Error on Refresh only

Tags: go, single-page-application, http-status-code-500

I have a golang API app that is currently serving double-duty as a Single Page App server with static content using the method shown here: https://hackandsla.sh/posts/2021-11-06-serve-spa-from-go/

Everything is working great in terms of navigation until users try to refresh URIs with encoded JSON in them. For example:

`/licenses`

will refresh file and draw the page as it would normally have appeared through internal `history.push()`

`/licenses/show/%7B"options":%7B"container":"home","field":"date","order":"desc"%7D,"license":"00001a"%7D`

will cause the 500 error.

I did the initial development with IIS as a web server so these Refresh errors never happened in that environment. And when the server is ready to be deployed I plan to use Caddy and reverse proxy the API and am assuming it will handle the Refreshes with the same aplomb as IIS.

But for now I am hoping to run tests against my simple server so I'd like to solve this issue out of curiosity in addition to development expediency.

Bottom line: What cause golang `http.ListenAndServe` to return 500 errors?

**UPDATE:**

As I need to be able to test and hand off for others I have converted to a querystring which `http.ListenAndServe` is happy with:

`/licenses/show/%7B"options":%7B"container":"home","field":"date","order":"desc"%7D,"license":"00001a"%7D`

causes 500 error

`/licenses/show?state=%7B"options":%7B"container":"home","field":"date","order":"desc"%7D,"license":"00001a"%7D`

works fine